# Make permanent changes to a webpage, through the webpage

Tags: php, html, mysql, css

Right this has been asked before in similar context but the answer was not given.. I need to know how to change the contents of "homepage.php" (Example) ***PERMANENTLY*** by filling out a form on the webpage itself, I know I have to store data in MySQL database but how should I go about doing this (which way). I know how to store and retrieve data but just this particular problem has me baffled.

Do I save single css values into the database (e.g. blue, green, margin-left, margin-right) or can I store a whole css block of code as a variable then save it in the database

|| body { //Content of body } .navbar{ //navbar content here }? ||

End result I need is to edit a page without altering the code so that everyone can see it not just by using cookies. (Please do not tell me about needing a server ETC I know..)

I am using the Procedural method of PHP programming with no framework for those seeking to give an example.

Thanks in Advance =D!

Comment: You want to save the entire content of a webpage in database?

Comment: This question is too broad.

Comment: You need to fill in some gaps of your question- do you want to allow the user to create modifications to style? To the structure of the page? Or to choose which css classes to use?

Comment: how do i store css information into a database i just need to know this i will work on the rest from this

Comment: There's a million ways to skin a cat. I think you can simply have a field "dynamic css" which looks like "div .some-class > p { color:#fff; }" which you can use to populate a .css file.

Comment: You just need to be a bit cautious of what's going into your db. css rules are littered with special characters, quotes, double quotes, etc. You can easily perform an injection attack with this.

Comment: "I am using the Procedural method of PHP programming with no framework for those seeking to give an example." What the heck is this supposed to mean? If you want to get anywhere in programming you'll need to open your thinking to new ideas. This sort of thing could be done in a day with a framework. Or, of course, you can bang your head against the wall with low-level procedural calls for weeks.

Comment: @tadman Go Away. you didnt answer your comment is invalid();

Comment: I gave you an answer right there. You're just too stubborn to accept it. For example, [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) has all the pieces you need for storing things in a database and rendering entire pages based on that. All you'd need to do is create a few models, hook it up with a few routes. Or, of course, you could skip all that as well and [use a PHP CMS](https://octobercms.com/).

Comment: I dont use laravel im still beginner, so the framework doesnt make sense to me why would I dive in at the deep end? i just want a simple question answered...

I am using just PHP so no frameworks thats what it means so if someone is going to give me an example i wont understand laravel or cake or whatever just PHP in its simplest form is this really do hard to udnerstand?

Answer (score 0):

I would post a comment but I don't have enough points to comment.
Would you be able to utilize jQuery for the webpage?  I have had to do this exact same thing with php/mysql, and using jQuery .css() and .html() provides a working solution.